# Azure Container Apps - How to import trusted 3rd party certificate

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-container-apps

The code in my azure container app is consuming an https endpoint.
The SSL certificate of endpoint  is issued by my company. All parent and root certificates are also issued the same way. I need to trust this certificate in my Azure Container App.

However I cannot see "Add public certificate (.cer)" option in related Container Apps Environment.
Azure App Service was giving this option, unfortunately Container Apps Environment doesn't.

How can I trust another SSL certificate in a container app?

PFX is not an option to me, because I do not know private key or password. I am only client.

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get this done ? I have a similar problem where I am using self signed certificate for private dns domain.

Comment: There is no smooth approach in Azure. I did it manually. I imported root certificate of the endpoint I am calling into /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ folder of container image.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I had to do the same, but imported the pem file that only had the public key in the /etc/ssl/certs directory